# Swift: Regex search in for loop not progressing

Tags: swift, regex

I am performing a regex search inside a loop but my implementation seems to get stuck, ie the search does not progress to the next cycle.

```
//At a function where I'm performing my regex search
let pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_]*)*[sS]uper([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_]*)*"

for text in array {
    let matches = listMatches(for: pattern, inString: text)
    print(matches)

}

print("Regex done") //When a break point is placed here, this never gets executed

func listMatches(for pattern: String, inString string: String) -> [String] {
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: []) else {
        return []
    }

    let range = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: range)

    return matches.map {
        let range = Range($0.range, in: string)!
        return String(string[range])
    }
}
```

I have about 5 texts inside `array`, and the `print(matches)` will print about 3 of the `matches`. The `for` loop never gets past the 4th or 5th cycle and the `print("Regex done")` never gets executed. The `text` size is typically about 1000 characters long.

Comment: `for text in array`, text is never called, did you meant `signatureHTML`? Also, do you have a code sample for `array`?

Comment: It is catastrophic backtracking - see the nested quantifiers at the start of the pattern (it is also at the end, but it is not important at the end.) Use `let pattern = "(?i)[A-Z0-9_-]*super[A-Z0-9_-]*"`

Comment: If it's not executing the `print` then... is there a crash log or something you can share?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your code contains several undefined variables that could be related to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*)*[sS]uper([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*)*` pattern you are using is very inefficient and is  fraught with [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). When you place a pattern of unlimited legth (as `a+` or `a*`) inside a group and set an unlimited quantifier to it (e.g. `(a+)+`) *and* the pattern is not at the end of the regex, catastrophic backtracking is imminent with strings that match the pattern partially, but not fully.

See a [demo of your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ZTI0zE/1) run against a short string like `Super`. Look, how hard it is for a regex engine to actually make sure that `Super` is the right match for the pattern, with red arrows showing backtracking:

[image]

Now, check how fast the pattern becomes if you unwrap the nested quantified patterns and use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[sS]uper[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZTI0zE/2), with the number of steps reduced from 167 to 13. Note you don't need to escape a `_` char (it is a *word* char), and you do not have to escape `-` inside a character class if it is at the start/end of the class.

If you use [`.caseInsensitive` option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412382-caseinsensitive) (e.g. `options: [ .caseInsensitive ]`), you may even shorten the pattern to `[a-z0-9_-]*super[a-z0-9_-]*`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I had no idea it is causing backtracking. I tried your code `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[sS]uper[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` and it works fine.